# LOAD INFILE instead of mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, bash

I have managed to set up a automated import of a table to my database with `mysqlimport`.

However it is not possible to see the details of any warnings. Instead I would like to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, with which it should be possible to add `SHOW WARNINGS`.

But I can not figure out how to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` in my bash script.

This is how I do it with `mysqlimport`:

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-enclosed-by=\" -u dbuser -ppassword databasename /tmp/customers.csv
```

This command imports the data into the table 'customers'.

But how can I do the same thing in my bash file with the added functionality of `SHOW WARNINGS`?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-e` or `--execute` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) to `mysql` will accept one or more queries separated by semicolons, just like in the interactive shell. Just pass it a standard [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) query followed by `SHOW WARNINGS`.

```
mysql -u dbuser -ppassword -D databasename -e 'LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/customers.csv" INTO TABLE foo FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY "\""; SHOW WARNINGS'
```

Or you can pass queries on standard input as well; I find [heredoc syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) easier to read and it avoids one level of quotes.

```
mysql -u dbuser -ppassword -D databasename <<SQL
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/customers.csv' INTO TABLE foo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
SHOW WARNINGS;
SQL
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. Unfortunately collation seems to go wrong. With mysqlimport foreign chars gets imported fine, but with LOAD DATA INFILE those characters gets messed up. Collation in both databases is: utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Managed to do it by adding : 

... INTO TABLE foo CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS ...

Thanks for all help.